# How to exclude the first 2 lines and only number list the rest of the file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to number list a certain section of the file but I'm not managing.

I want the IP section to be numbered only

Here is what I want to have:

[Output of what I would like][1]

Here is what I get:

[Output of what I get][2]

3. echo "Number         Server"
   echo "--------       --------"
   nl server.list.txt
   echo -n "Enter the server number to delete: " select
   read select
   if [[ $select -eq 3 ]]
   then
   sed -i '3d' server.list.txt #deletes the 3rd line
   elif [[ $select -eq 4 ]]
   then
   sed -i '4d' server.list.txt #deletes the 4th line
   elif [[ $select -eq 5 ]]
   then
   sed -i '5d' server.list.txt #deletes the 5th line
   else
   echo "****************************************"
   echo "ERROR: The number entered is invalid !!!"
   echo "****************************************"
   fi;;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: You've shown us actual and expected output, but not the input. It's hard to help you write a tool to parse some input if you don't show us the input so please [edit] your question to add the input that would produce that output.

Comment: Is the original file tab-delimited?

Comment: We don't need/want to see your full code, just a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input, expected output and a small but complete piece of code that attempts to do just what you're asking for help with in this question.

Comment: For example: your question subject is `How to exclude the first 2 lines and only number list the rest of the file?` so to get an answer for **that**, provide an input file that's, say, 5 lines long, an output file that's numbered except for the first 2 lines, and the code you wrote to try to do just **that**. If afterwards you have another question about some other part of your code, then ask a new question repeating that process.

Comment: Replacing all the nicely formatted code and data with unformatted code and images does *not*  improve the question. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The purpose of this site is not only to answer a question for you personally but as a reference for others that might have a similar problem. You have added the code from the answer to your question and made it nearly unreadable. Please revert the changes to your question in a way that it matches the answer again. Otherwise we might rollback to an earlier version of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sed` to print the first two lines with spaces at the beginning.

Then use `tail` to pipe the rest of the file to `nl`.

```
sed -n '1,2s/^/   /' server.list.txt
tail -n +3 server.list.txt | nl
```

Comment: That answered my first problem. My second problem is that I am trying to put the numbers in a column and put the IP addresses in the second column. It would be the same as I showed above but replace "Server IP" with "Number" and replace "User" with "Server IP" if that makes sense

Comment: @LukeGalea if you have a second problem then ask a second question. [Chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged on this forum. There may be other possible answers to your current question though, we'll know more once you show us the input.

Comment: @LukeGalea If this is a separate problem, write a new question. If you found out that your question above is incomplete, edit the question and add all requirements including input file, user input, expected output.

Comment: This all sounds like a job for `awk`. @LukeGalea